# PHP coding got an error

Tags: php

```
 <?php
$conn=mysql_connect(`localhost'," root","") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("bng_nov",$conn) or die("could not connect database");
?>
```

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '`' in C:\xampp\htdocs\display\db.php on line 4**

Comment: Just replace the qoutes on localhost, like $conn=mysql_connect("localhost", " root", "") or die("Could not connect");

Comment: You should also try looking into myssqli_ or PDO as mysql_ has been deprecated for some time and removed from the latest versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in this line replace (`) with (') single quote. also remove space before root

```
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost',"root","") or die("Could not connect");
```

and best solution is use double quotes like this

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect");
```

also i mention that don't use `mysql_*`. you should used `mysqli_*`

i have add some DB connectivity codes. used this code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\display\db.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\display\index.php(3): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\display\db.php on line 2

Comment: have that error huhu

Comment: what is your PHP version?

Comment: i used notepad+ to do php coding

Comment: buddy my question is what's your PHP version? notepad++ is your text editor

Comment: read this article to check php version https://www.wikihow.com/Check-PHP-Version

Comment: @ScottyYong i have add some code in my answer used this code to connect your data base

Comment: ok i try it later .. will give you feedback while i tried it .. thank

Comment: can already bro ..

Answer (score 0):

error in the below line

```
$conn=mysql_connect(`localhost'," root","")
```

please try like below

```html
<?php
if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('bng_nov', $link)) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;

}
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\display\db.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\display\index.php(3): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\display\db.php on line 2

Comment: @ScottyYong updated code plz try

Comment: ok will try now .. will give you feedback later